# ASP.NET MVC site having problems with MACs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos

We have a site at: http://www.racedayworld.com which was built using ASP.NET MVC

There are currently a couple people who cannot use the login form when using a Safari on the MAC. The problem is a strange one as I (the developer) have a MAC and can login just fine with Safari. What happens is they put in their credentials and the site just reloads, but doesn't log them in...

I'm including 2 examples of the support details we collected from them to see if there was any common problems..

- Operating System Apple Mac OS X 10.6.4 Intel
- Screen Resolution 1280 x 800
- Web Browser Safari 5.0.2
- Browser Size 1190 x 690
- Color Depth 24 bit
- Javascript Yes
- Flash Version 10 (10.0.45)
- Cookies Yes
- User AgentMozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5

---

- Operating System Apple Mac OS X 10.5.8 Intel
- Screen Resolution 1440 x 900
- Web Browser Safari 5.0
- Browser Size 1440 x 776
- Color Depth 24 bit
- Javascript Yes
- Flash Version 10 (10.0.45)
- Cookies Yes
- User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.16

Comment: Are they clicking a login button or hitting enter?  Reason I ask is sometimes if the submit doesnt have focus for one reason or another...the site will just refresh.

Comment: both - I've gone to their individual machines and tried it myself but no dice

Comment: Good looking site by the way...

Comment: thanks Matt! only thing I don't like right now is the accordian for the events .. need to figure out a way to make that more intuitive  ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cookie issue to me

Comment: Thanks, could you be any more vague?

Comment: Just kidding, it might be - but yeah could you be more specific?

(this was supposed to go with that last comment, but I pressed enter to get to the next line and it inserted it .. now I just sound like an ungrateful a$$)

Comment: @Kevin, well MVC uses a cookie to store that the user was authenticated during a session. It could be that they aren't allowing third party cookies to be set thus causing the MVC to just redirect back to the login page when it redirects to the page.

Comment: Although the support details I got back from them said that cookies were on ... Safari disables third party cookies by default yes? But if that's the case, why would it work on some, but not others?

Comment: Really, this is a almost 2 year old answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a very similar error before with MVC & Safari & logging in.  Try checking the log files in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR and see if there are any 400 server errors.  Have you also checked main event viewer logs for any server errors?

Comment: I'll check the logs - but if there are what would that mean in terms of solving the issue?

Comment: I haven't found the resolution yet. But I have been able to reproduce it - just not very frequently.  Being logged into facebook & also having a facebook widget on the site has increased its frequency, which makes me wonder if its related to those cookies it sets.

Comment: Hmmm .. considering I have access to one of the individuals who is having the problem, I should be able to take off the Facebook widget, then get them to try it out to see if that is making a difference...

Comment: Testing on Safari Mac & Logged into facebook works fine for me too. I would check your log files, including the less common HTTPERR file I mentioned.